# Let $ \{A_{n}\} $ be a sequence of measurable sets

Tags: measure-theory

Let $ \{A_{n}\} $ be a sequence of measurable sets , **then show that $ \\ \ P(\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} A_{n}) \geq 1-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P(A_{n}^{c})**. $  $$ $$ We know that if  $ \{A_{n}\} $ is measurable , then $ P(\cap _{n=1}^{\infty} A_{n} )$ is also measurable. Now, $ \begin {align}  \cap A_{n} \subset A_{1} \\ \cap A_{n} \subset A_{2}\\   \cap A_{n} \subset  A_{3} \\ ... so \ on  \\ or, P(\cap A_{n}) \leq P(A_{1}=1-P(A_{n}) \\ P(\cap A_{n}) \leq P(A_{2})=1-P(A_{2}) \\ and \ so \ on .  \end{align}. $   . Any help is appreciating .

Comment: The inequality doesn't seem right. The left hand side is non-negative, while the right hand side might very well be negative.

Comment: Do you mean $\le$ or $\ge$?

Comment: Let $A_1 = A_2=\emptyset$, then the left hand side is $0$ and the right hand side is negative.

Comment: it is my mistake the actual inequality , is $ P( \bigcap A_{n}) \geq 1- \sum P(A_{n}) $

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$1-P\left(\bigcap A_n\right) = P\left(\left(\bigcap A_n\right)^c\right)= P\left(\bigcup A_n^c\right).$$

Comment: But is it true $ P(\bigcup A_{n}^{c}) \leq  \sum P(A_{n}^{c}) $

Comment: @mabmath Sure. See proofs of this fact: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/270393/413376