# Prove Boole's inequality $P\left(\ \bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i\right) \leq \sum_{i=1}^n P(A_i)$ without induction.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality

I can prove :
$$ P\left(\ \bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i\right) \leq \sum_{i=1}^n P(A_i) $$
using induction. I was wondering whether there is any way to prove this without using induction, starting from scratch, using only the probability axioms.

Comment: Technically, there's no way to even define notations such as $\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n P(A_i)$ without using recursion, so a truly induction-free proof is therefore impossible (although there are probably ways to hide it the same way one hides the recursion in the notations' definitions).

Comment: Sorry, modified the infinite union/sums to finite

Comment: @greg martin one can define $\cup A_i$ as the set $\{ x : \exists i ,~x \in A_i\}$ which does not use recursion.

Comment: Also this is my favovite answer to your question : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/270394. This proof only uses one axiom which is required to be a measure (not necessarily a probability measure).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$P(\cup_{i=1}^n A_i) = \int_{\cup_{i=1}^n A_i} P(d\omega) \le \sum_{i=1}^n \int_{A_i} P(d\omega) = \sum_{i=1}^n P(A_i)$$

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit as to what all your notation means and provide some more intuition ?

Comment: If $P$ is discrete, $P(A)=\sum_{w\in A}P(\{w\})$. If $A\subseteq \mathbb R$ and $P$ is absolutely continuous with density $f$, $P(A)=\int_A \, P(d\omega)= \int_A f(x)\, dx$.

Comment: Edit: $A\subseteq \mathbb R$ should be replaced by '$A$ is a Borel-measurable subset of $\mathbb R$'

Answer (score 1):

If $X$ is a non-negative integer random variable, then $$P(X\geq 1)\leq E(X).\tag1$$

In particular, if $X$ is the number of values $i$ such that the sample is in $A_i,$ then (1) is equivalent to your inequality.

However, the only real way to prove that equivalence formally I’ll be induction.

Answer (score 1):

Highlighting the key point of maliesen's computation:
$$
1_{\cup_{i=1}^n A_i}(\omega)\le\sum_{i=1}^n 1_{A_i}(\omega),
$$
because the right side is at least $1$ if $\omega\in A_i$ for at least one index $i$. Now take expectations.

This inequality (and so the proof) is true even for an infinite sequence $A_1, A_2, \ldots$.

(Although induction my be involved in the *definition* of $\cup_{i=1}^n A_i$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n P(A_i)$, and in basic properties of these objects, once these properties are established induction need not enter into the proof of Boole.)